# USB Toshiba (16Gb) not recognized

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount

I have a **16Gb USB** and when I connect it to my computer nothing happens.

- I tried to find my usb using `fdisk -l` but it doesn't appear
- I tried also `blkid` but it doesn't appear neither
- I've used also `gparted` but it doesn't appear neither
- I use `dmesg` after connecting the USB and this is the output:

**dmesg** output:

```
[73053.848388] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[73053.918701] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: port 1 reset error -110
[73055.028237] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[73055.173576] usb 5-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[73055.205570] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=6544
[73055.205584] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[73055.205592] usb 5-1: Product: TransMemory     
[73055.205599] usb 5-1: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA 
[73055.205605] usb 5-1: SerialNumber: 7427EAB35023CDA16394BF3E
[73055.209518] usb-storage 5-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[73055.209796] scsi17 : usb-storage 5-1:1.0
[73056.481378] scsi 17:0:0:0: Direct-Access     GENERIC  USB Mass Storage 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4 CCS
[73056.481756] sd 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[73056.506350] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
[73056.506358] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[73056.506361] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[73056.506364] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[73056.506367] Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
[73056.506372] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[73056.506379] Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
[73056.509339] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[73056.509345] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
[73056.512355] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[73056.541347] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
[73056.541354] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[73056.541358] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[73056.541361] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[73056.541364] Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
[73056.541369] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[73056.541375] Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
[73056.554349] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Some interesting parts from the dmesg output:

```
[73056.506350] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
[73056.541375] Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
```

## Edit

About @Helio question:

If I make `ls /dev/sdb` the output is:

```
/dev/sdb
```

If I make `fdisk /dev/sdb` the output is:

```
fdisk: unable to read /dev/sdb: Invalid argument
```

That seems to be logic because of the error:

```
[sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
```

Comment: It contains data? Please post the output of `ls /dev/sd*`

Comment: It is new so Ill say no, but I cant see

Comment: @Helio sorry for the delay, I edited the question with the info

Comment: Try to run `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/pendrive-fix.conf` and then paste on this empty file this line: `options usb_storage delay_use=5`, save and reboot. If it works, then I'll post a explained solution.

Answer (score 0):

Of course each situation will be different, but I just had this same thing happen with a USB flash drive. It's one I'd had for several years, and I would often have to unplug/replug it several times to get it to work. This time it wouldn't work at all.

My solution was to clean the contacts of the drive with rubbing alcohol. After that it worked perfectly.

In case it helps, here are a few of the errors I was getting:

```
[47908.871713] usb 3-1: can't set config #1, error -71
[47924.750591] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
[47924.750678] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
```